# How to read a non-text file containing EOF characters in C?

Tags: c, file, eof

I'm trying to loop over all bytes of a file using a simple `while` loop, like so:

```c
char c = fgetc(InputFile);

while (c != EOF)
    {
        doStuff(c)
        c = fgetc(InputFile);
    }
```

However, when working with non-text files, I've found that some of the bytes within the file (that aren't the last one) contain the value 255, and therefore register as EOF and the while loop ends prematurely.

How do I get around this and loop over ***all*** bytes?

Comment: `c` should be `int`.

Comment: `EOF` is not a character, it's a signal ... like if you ask your teacher how old she is and she tells you "Go to hell"... you ask your system to give you a character, and it says "nope, no character for you now; have a signal instead"

Comment: `EOF`, an `int` ,  and `255` as `int` are not going to be the same. Your core problem is as Eugene pointed out; `c` should be `int`.

Comment: You'll find that almost *every* (if not all) library functions that take or return a character use the `int` type, not `char`. "Character" does not always mean `char` and in fact `'A'` is of type `int`.

Comment: So simple I feel kinda silly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you should assign the value returned by `fgetc` to an `int` variable, not a `char`. That way, you will be able to distinguish between a successfully input character that has the hex value `0xFF` (`fgetc` will return 255) and a end-of-file condition (`fgetc` will return `EOF`, which is -1).

From the [cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) for `fgetc`:

> On success, returns the obtained character as an unsigned char
> converted to an int. On failure, returns EOF.